# Adding a child view to a custom view within Android, programmatically

Tags: android, layout, webview, imagebutton, custom-view

What I am trying to do is simply add an imageButton view as a child of a custom view, in the top right corner.  My custom view extends Webview.  I have had no problem adding the imageButton to my custom view, I just can't move it to the top right corner.  I need to do this programmatically, not in xml. I would never think something this simple would require me to post on here, but I really can't figure it out.

Here is what I am using to add the imageButton to the custom view currently, but it's at the top left corner:

```
    public class customView extends WebView {

      private void imageButtonInit() {
         ImageButton closeImageButton = new ImageButton(getContext());
         Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(com.package.image);
         closeImageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(image);
         closeImageButton.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(25, 25));
         closeImageButton.bringToFront();
         customView.this.addView(closeImageButton);
      }
    }
```

What I have tried in order to move it to the top right corner:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(25, 25);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, -1);
    closeImageButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
    customView.this.addView(closeImageButton);
```

As well as:

```
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(25, 25, Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.TOP);
    closeImageButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
    customView.this.addView(closeImageButton);
```

All of which results in the imageButton being placed in the top left corner.  This is my first post on this site so I hope the question is properly formatted.  Please no xml solutions.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are doing in  your other two methods is literally setting your *CustomView* to have those layout params. What you should try instead is set the layout params of your child using this method;

```
    customView.this.addView(child, params);
```

where child is your image button and params is the layout params.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Richard.  I actually meant to write     closeImageButton.setLayoutParams(lp);  that was a typo.  Sorry.

Comment: And although the method you suggested looks like it should work, the button still remains in the top left corner.

Comment: Perhaps there is other settings in your custom view that isn't properly being handled. What is stopping you from creating a custom RelativeLayout, calling it your customView, and including both your custom web view and a button with settings on top left? It would still be contained in one "view"

Comment: I'll let you know by tomorrow.

Comment: Hey Richard.  The solution of creating a custom layout definately works, but it is not something I am able to do based on what I'm building.  I did some more research and apparently webviews don't support any sort of layout params for child views.  I'm just going to write the button using javascript.  Giving you a tick for a solution that technically worked, though. :)

Comment: Interesting -- ill keep that in mind! Hope your javascript solution works out, thanks for the update